# Commands see files, bash doesn't

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, vmware-workstation

This is a really odd bug I can't seem to figure it out.  Basically, commands like `ls` can see all the files in the current directory, however when I go to execute the file it will give errors like "file not found", even when it most obviously is.

[image]

If you look at my command history in the screenshot, you can see I can `ls` into a directory and see it's contents.  When I try to run the file, I get the "no such file or directory" error.

However, if I type simply 'vm', I can't use tab completion to complete the directory name, and my third command is me typing 'vm' and hitting <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, it lists a bunch of vmware specific tools instead of the subdirectory name.  I can then `ls` and see my current directory contents, and it will list only the single subdirectory.  However, then I tried to use the full filepath from root to run the file, still to no avail.  If anyone has any insight, it would be much appreciated.

FYI it's Ubuntu Server 10.04 inside VMWare Workstation.

Comment: As current dir (or your HOME dir in this case) is not in PATH , vm TAB TAB will not expand it. ./vm TAB TAB will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the filename is listed in red tells me that it's likely a broken symlink.

If you do `ls -l vmware-tools-distrib/vmware-install.pl` you'll probably see something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group   10 2010-09-10 10:19 vmware-install.pl -> non-existent-target
```

Comment: This is correct, thank you.  When I ran the installer the first time, it did not complete successfully, but it managed to change the link the install was file pointed to to a non-existent uninstall file.  I thought I could just re-run the install after installing the necessary libraries, but apparently not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to execute a command, bash searches for that command in PATH. The current working directory is usually not included in PATH for security reasons (to avoid Trojan horse attacks). To execute a command in the current directory, precede its name with `./`, e.g.,

```
./vmstat
```

EDIT: Never mind--didn't read question carefully.